# Python function SOS

Tags: python, function

I have a second degree equation a*x^2 + b*x + c. I am allowed to pass only a,b,c values as parameters and fill only return line. How am I going to give a value to x?

```
def make_quadratic(a,b,c):

return ________________
```

> f = make_quadratic(1, 2, 1.0)
>
> f(0) = 1.0

Answer (score 3):

From your example, `make_quadratic` returns a function (`f`). You can either define a function explicitly (`def f(x): ...; return f`), or use lambda, essentially an in-line function

`return lambda x: a*x*x + b*x + c`

Comment: @DeepSpace did you look at OPs example?

Comment: @DeepSpace the problem isn't "solve for X", the problem is "build a function you can pass X to".

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_quadratic(a, b, c):
    def F(x):
        return a * x ** 2 + b * x + c
    return F


f = make_quadratic(1, 2, 1.0)
print(f(0))
```